# When was Nazi paramilitary organisation Waffen-SS liquidated in the legal sense?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, law

Armed forces of Third Reich consisted of two groups: proper public/national army "[Wehrmacht](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wehrmacht)" and private paramilitary organization "[Waffen-SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffen-SS)" which was an armed branch of SS (Schutzstaffel, "protection squadron"). Waffen-SS was considered to be elite forces, it was well funded and had the best military technology at its disposal. When [military surrender act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_Instrument_of_Surrender) was signed in 1945 it was only about Wehrmacht and not Waffen-SS. In 1947 during [Nuremberg Trials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuremberg_trials) (military tribunals held by the Allied forces under international law) SS (and so, Waffen-SS) was declared "criminal" organisation. But was it in any way *legally* liquidated by some *German* court or other *German* institution?

I'm asking because many things were made in some informal or legally complex ways those days. For example, [in a fully legal sense state of war with Germany for many countries was ended between 1951-1955](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_status_of_Germany#State_of_war) and *not* in 1945. And Germany regained full sovereignity in 1991.

UPDATE:

I was able to find that the Military Government in United States Zone issued [Law No. 52](http://www.flegel-g.de/PDF/SHAEF52.pdf) declaring all **properties** of SS to be "subject to seizure of possession of title, direction, management, supervision, or otherwise". Then, there was [General Order No. 1](http://www.flegel-g.de/PDF/SHAEF52.pdf) which states that Military Law No. 52 shall apply up to the date of "dissolution, abrogation or suspension" of the SS. It means that it didn't liquidate the SS.

In the comments, @kimchilover, pointed to the [Berlin Declaration](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Berlin_Declaration_(1945)), but it only orders **weapons and equipment disarming** (art 2 par. a) and declares **personnel to be prisoners of war** (art 2 par b). There is nothing about legal termination of SS or its agencies.

Comment: I suppose Article 2 of the "Berlin Declaration" (https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Berlin_Declaration_(1945)) cuts no ice with you?

Comment: @kimchilover, Berlin Declaration orders weapons and equipment disarming (art 2 par. a) and declares personnel to be prisoners of war (art 2 par b). There is nothing about legal termination of SS or its agencies.

Comment: The Waffen SS is hardly paramilitary. The paramilitary organisation would be the old SA and to a degree the SD, plus the personal protection detail for high ranking officials (which may or may not have been Waffen SS members rather than regular SS). The Waffen SS was a full military organisation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe I've finally found the answer: [Law No. 2 "Providing for the Termination and Liquidation of Nazi Organizations"](http://images.library.wisc.edu/History/EFacs/GerRecon/PropControl/reference/history.propcontrol.i0037.pdf) issued **10 October 1945** by Allied Control Authority Control Council. Waffen-SS, is explicitly mentioned in the appendix under point 55.

Comment: Beat me by a minute.  Alternative copy: https://www.loc.gov/rr/frd/Military_Law/Enactments/Volume-I.pdf